# Boost Serialization of simple class with RTTI turned Off (-fno-rtti)

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, g++, rtti

I am trying to serialize a simple class with Plain-old-Data types using boost serialization.  However, my only requirement is that I cannot use RTTI.  Thus I am compiling with -fno-rtti using gcc 4.4.1 for ARM Linux with latest Boost 1.47 library.

So here is my class:

```
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>

class libNemoMemento
{
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    private:
        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(temperature);
            ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(voltage);
            ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(bandwidth);
            ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(power);
        }
        int temperature;
        unsigned int voltage;
        unsigned int bandwidth;
        unsigned char power;
    public:
        libNemoMemento(void) {}
        virtual ~libNemoMemento(void) {}
};
```

I haven't even implemented the actual save and load functions yet (they seem to be pretty straightforward from looking at the Boost documentation) but I am already getting the following compiler errors:

```
In file included from /home/me/prebuild/third-party/boost/include/boost/serialization/detail/shared_ptr_132.hpp:29,
                 from /home/me/third-party/boost/include/boost/serialization/shared_ptr_132.hpp:35,
                 from /home/me/third-party/boost/include/boost/archive/shared_ptr_helper.hpp:29,
                 from /home/me/third-party/boost/include/boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp:133,
                 from serialize_test.h:21,
                 from serialize_test.cpp:15:
/home/me/third-party/boost/include/boost/serialization/detail/shared_count_132.hpp: In member function 'virtual void* boost_132::detail::sp_counted_base_impl<P, D>::get_deleter(const std::type_info&)':
/home/me/third-party/boost/include/boost/serialization/detail/shared_count_132.hpp:274: error: cannot use typeid with -fno-rtti
In file included from /home/me/prebuild/third-party/boost/include/boost/serialization/shared_ptr_132.hpp:35,
                 from /home/me/prebuild/third-party/boost/include/boost/archive/shared_ptr_helper.hpp:29,
                 from /home/me/prebuild/third-party/boost/include/boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp:133,
                 from serialize_test.h:21,
                 from serialize_test.cpp:15:
/home/me/prebuild/third-party/boost/include/boost/serialization/detail/shared_ptr_132.hpp: In function 'D* boost_132::get_deleter(const boost_132::shared_ptr<U>&)':
/home/me/prebuild/third-party/boost/include/boost/serialization/detail/shared_ptr_132.hpp:465: error: cannot use typeid with -fno-rtti
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

So.. the question is, is it possible to serialize this simple class using boost serialization without using RTTI??  I have looked around and it seems like it may be possible using some boost macros and machinery (#include < boost/serialization/extended_type_info_no_rtti.hpp > alludes to this) but I am a new Boost user and pretty clueless as to how to proceed.

PS: My code compiles fine if I remove -fno-rtti.

Comment: When RTTI is turned off, the compiler is no longer standard conforming. Don't do that unless you know what the consequences are.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I suppose I just have to enable rtti if I wanna use boost::serialize.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/boost-serialization-and-RTTI-td2566883.html

Comment: Looks like it was never implemented AFAIK.

Comment: Please give at least a summary of the contents of the link in case it goes down.