# boost unit test fails with error - std::bad_typeid: Access violation - no RTTI data

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

I am trying to serialize set of classes (where every class which has virtual destructor) using boost serialization. Test for all classes are passing except 1 which give above error.

I even tried setting enabling RTTI in VS 2012 but no use.. still the error exists.

I saw a link with similar type of issue but no help.

[Boost Serialization of simple class with RTTI turned Off (-fno-rtti)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856277/boost-serialization-of-simple-class-with-rtti-turned-off-fno-rtti)

**complete error message is - unknown location(0): fatal error in "mychecktest": std::bad_typeid: Access violation - no RTTI data!**

There is another link on similar problem but no solution
http://lists.boost.org/boost-testing/2005/05/1014.php

really don't know what could go wrong... really need help on this.

Thanks,

Comment: even after enabling RTTI in VS 2010.. still getting same error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my case, i was also getting same issue and it was due to 1 of member variables was not serializing properly and hence this issue occured.
You can also do the same check at and give it a try.

Comment: you are correct.. indeed.. it is failing at 1 point..and if i comment it .. it runs fine..